# Printing to a printer install in XP Mode on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printer, windows-xp-mode

At work iPrint is used to manage all the printers. I am messing around with Windows 7 which currently is not supported by by the iprint software or printer drivers. I can install the software and printers in XP Mode and am wondering if there is a way of printing to that printer from windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can install the printer on XP Mode and then share it. Not the best way to go about it but that's how I did it for a while while trying to figure out what drivers I needed.